# Azure Service Fabric Deploy: Is there a way to force remove an application prior to deployment? Or Force an upgrade that is same version?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-service-fabric, continuous-deployment

When I go to deploy my new release, I am getting the error

> 2016-12-02T22:38:07.5926507Z ##[error]An application with name
>   'fabric:/MyApp' already exists, its type is 'MyApp' and version is
>   '1.0.0'. You must first remove the existing application before a new
>   application can be deployed or provide a new name for the application.

Is there an argument I can pass or something so I can force it to be removed prior to deploy?

On Another note, I tried to upgrade, but since it isn't a new version, I believe it is just hanging as I get:

```
557  2016-12-02T23:16:59.9097292Z Waiting for upgrade... 
558  2016-12-02T23:17:02.9187447Z Waiting for upgrade... 
559  2016-12-02T23:17:05.9277026Z Waiting for upgrade... 
560  2016-12-02T23:17:08.9348253Z Waiting for upgrade... 
561  2016-12-02T23:17:10.4834230Z ##[error]The operation was canceled. 
562  2016-12-02T23:17:10.4834230Z ##[section]Finishing: Deploy Service Fabric Application
```

For 30 minutes until it times out.  Any idea on what I should be doing here?

UPDATE 2016-12-05
Now I am getting other strange errors trying to run update:

```
2016-12-05T20:46:14.3605004Z Successfully connected to cluster.    
2016-12-05T20:46:14.4049221Z Searching for path: C:\a\r1\a    
2016-12-05T20:46:16.1629321Z No items were found with search pattern C:\a\r1\a.    
2016-12-05T20:49:43.8787335Z ##[warning]Failed to contact Naming Service. 
Attempting to contact Failover Manager Service...    
2016-12-05T20:51:03.5403730Z Copying application to image store...    
2016-12-05T21:05:13.7670311Z ##[error]Operation timed out.    
2016-12-05T21:05:13.8430325Z ##[section]Finishing: Deploy Service Fabric Application
```

Comment: If you use regular deployment mode existing deployment will be deleted and a new deployment will be made.

Comment: What's the detail upgrade settings of your build and what's the detail build log? To remove fabric application, you can consider REST API (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/servicefabric/delete-an-application)

Comment: @Aravind Are there any errors in Service Fabric Explorer? I can't reproduce that issue. What's the result if you publish Fabric App through Visual Studio?

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that the new the app does not have a new version compared to what is on the cluster?  Are you making use of the **Update Service Fabric App Versions** build task?  If so, that will likely be automatically updating the versions in your manifests as part of the build.  In which case, it would make sense that you'd see this error since the deployment logic currently doesn't let you overwrite an app with a different version.

Comment: You can't over write with a new version?  Well if that is the case, fine, but then why won't my upgrade upgrade?  If just says "waiting for upgrade" until it times out.

Comment: Not currently, no.  It's designed to be a safeguard to prevent you from accidentally overwriting an app instead of upgrading it, since a newer version often implies that you want to upgrade.

Not sure why the upgrade would just fail like that.  Try connecting to the cluster's Service Fabric Explorer during the upgrade and see if it provides any helpful messages.